# Flutter: Unable to display correct word using hex value for QCF_BSML font

Tags: flutter, dart, hex, unicode-escapes

In my flutter application I'm using qcf_bsml font, I have to generate the hex values to display the corresponding words in the font file. For that, I'm using this equation:
**(64396 + Id >= 64434) ? 64429 + chapterId : 64396 + Id**

I convert the result from above to hex value using this function:

```
 calculatehex(){

   final myInteger = (64396 + 1 >= 64434) ? 64429 + 1 : 64396 + 1; //Id is 1: result 64397
   final hexString = myInteger.toRadixString(16);
   final paddedString = hexString.padLeft(4, '0');
    uppercaseString = paddedString.toUpperCase();
   print(uppercaseString); //displays correct hex value in console :FB8D
 
 }
```

The problem is I am only able to hardcode the hex value in text field to display the correct word. For example:

```
new  Text('\u{FB8D}',textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style:TextStyle(fontSize:30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,fontFamily: 'QCF'),
                        textAlign:TextAlign.center ), // works fine
```

But if I use the variable name to display text, it displays the wrong word.

```
new  Text(uppercaseString,textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style:TextStyle(fontSize:30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,fontFamily: 'QCF'),
                        textAlign:TextAlign.center ), // not showing correct word
```

I tried to concatenate the string like this, but still not working fine

```
new  Text(r'\u{'+uppercaseString+'}',textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        style:TextStyle(fontSize:30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,fontFamily: 'QCF'),
                        textAlign:TextAlign.center ),
```

Please help me understand why is it display the correct word with hardcoded value with '\u' but not with variable. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using String.fromCharCode(int.parse()) & making following changes in the code:

```
 uppercaseString = paddedString.toUpperCase();
finalhexString ='0x$uppercaseString';
```

then:

```
new  Text(String.fromCharCode(int.parse(finalhexString)),textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    style:TextStyle(fontSize:30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,fontFamily: 'QCF'),
                    textAlign:TextAlign.center ),
```